# any software to recommend to use with Webdav Protocol?

Tags: windows, webdav

Any software to recommend to work with server supporting webdav?

Comment: Shopping recommendations are strictly forbidden on Super User per the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there's Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 express which is a free web editing tool, the successor to front page = http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/

Or you can try Net Drive = http://www.netdrive.net/ - which turns the web dav into a networked HD in your explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Windows has built-in support for WebDAV.

- *Computer - Map Network Drive*
- *Network - Add Network Place*
- `net use \\server\path`